# What should I do to care for a small olive tree in the winter (South Wales)?

Tags: winter-gardening, olive

What should I do to care for an olive tree when it gets cold (here in the UK)? The tree is about 3 feet tall and I have access to a greenhouse (unheated).

Comment: Does it mean you have it in the pot, or you are thinking about transplanting it?

Comment: @theUg it probably doesn't need to be transplanted yet, but yes, it's in a pot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should transfer your tree into your greenhouse, but try to select a shady but not dark place.

Irrigate the tree only a little bit, the substrate in the pot should not dry out.
Check the temperature in your greenhouse regulary, it should not go below 10°C the whole day for a long period (f.e. in december/january/february), and you should ventilate your glasshouse once a week. If the temperature goes down too much, you can use jute-textiles or similar to wrap the tree.